# How to find 3rd point of equilateral triangle from two points at any angle in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, geometry

I have two points of an equilateral triangle, how can I calculate the third one?

I have this illustration:

[image: Hexagon illustration with dots as verticies]

And I want to draw triangles on each edge, so I need 3rd point.

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler approach for specific case of equilateral triangle. Magic number is `sqrt(3)/2=cos(60)`, so expressions are equivalent to yours.

```
function third(p1, p2) {
    const x = (p1.x + p2.x)/2 - 0.8660254 * (p1.y - p2.y);
    const y = (p1.y + p2.y)/2 + 0.8660254 * (p1.x - p2.x);
    return { x, y };
}
```

(perhaps +/- before 0.866 should be swapped to get needed side for vertex)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the 3rd point of an Equilateral triangle by rotating it by 60 degrees using a known equation from trigonometry.
So this is also an answer to how to rotate one point by another point.
It's known because it's something you have in high school in analytic geometry class:

The code uses JavaScript, I'm answering here because I was not able to find the answer.

```js
function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function rotate(p1, p2, angle) {
    const a = deg2rad(angle);
    const x = (p1.x - p2.x) * Math.cos(a) - (p1.y - p2.y) * Math.sin(a) + p2.x;
    const y = (p1.x - p2.x) * Math.sin(a) + (p1.y - p2.y) * Math.cos(a) + p2.y;
    return { x, y };
}

const point_c = rotate(point_a, point_b, 60);
```